# How to generate ANR report in Firebase Crashlytics Android?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

My application is published in other distribution(Not play store), I want to generate ANR logs in Firebase Crashlytics Android.

I am using firebase Bom library and its working in android 11 but not working in lower then 11

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

Answer (score 0):

The API being by Crashlytics to obtain ANRs is "[getHistoricalProcessExitReasons](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/ActivityManager#gethistoricalprocessexitreasons)" which is only available on Android 11+ devices.

Check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=android#anr-requires-android-11-plus) for reference.